# How to prove that a function for freeing a linked list is badly written?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linked-list

A question regarding the linked lists in C. Suppose, we have the following structures, that define the nodes in a linked list and a badly written free_list function, that (in my opinion) should cause an error:

```
typedef struct node *nodeT;

typedef struct node
{
    int* elem;
    nodeT next;
} *nodeT;

void free_list(nodeT list)
{
    nodeT node;

    for (node = list; node; node = node->next)
    {
        free(node->elem);
        free(node);
    }
}
```

As you see above, we have defined node as **nodeT** and a function to free the list **free_list**. For me, the obvious error is that inside **free_list** function inside **for** we do not have a temporary pointer to store the **node** value.

However, when I compile the code (on Linux), in which I create a linked list with few elements, the program doesn't crash, it seems that everything works fine.

**My question is**: Is there a simple way to prove that this function (**free_list**) is badly written? By simple I mean setting up some compiler flags (`-Wall` doesn't show any errors) or using such tools as `Valgrind` (used it with `memcheck`, that didn't help much)?

**Update**: Test case as requested:

```
int main()
{
    nodeT myType;
    nodeT tmpPtr;

    myType = malloc(sizeof(nodeT));
    myType->item = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(myType->item) = 0;
    myType->next = malloc(sizeof(nodeT));
    tmpPtr = myType->next;

    tmpPtr->item = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(tmpPtr->item) = 1;
    tmpPtr->next = malloc(sizeof(nodeT));
    tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;

    tmpPtr->item = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(tmpPtr->item) = 2;
    tmpPtr->next = malloc(sizeof(nodeT));
    tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;

    tmpPtr->item = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(tmpPtr->item) = 3;
    tmpPtr->next = NULL;

    free_list(myType);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the `Valgrind` output:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out
...
==4318== Invalid read of size 8
==4318==    at 0x400579: free_list (in /home/melon/a.out)
==4318==    by 0x40069E: main (in /home/melon/a.out)
==4318==  Address 0x51f1048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 free'd
==4318==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4318==    by 0x400574: free_list (in /home/melon/a.out)
==4318==    by 0x40069E: main (in /home/melon/a.out)
...
```

Comment: Did you ran Valgrind against this? What did it say?

Comment: I am surprised to hear that valgrind doesn't catch the error. Could you include the *entire* test case, so that we can experiment with it?

Comment: Fill the list with several elements and invoke `free_list` to see what happens. It's good to do this through valgrind

Comment: You have already "proved" that it's badly written, by static analysis.

Comment: I must have omitted the last output of `Valgrind`. Everything was there. Thanks for help and suggestions!

Comment: You could try using http://frama-c.com/ to prove your program and provide ACSL annotations ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you did the test with valgrind, but with default parameters it detects this issue just fine:

```
==4464== Invalid read of size 8
==4464==    at 0x400571: free_list (list.c:15)
==4464==    by 0x4005DF: main (list.c:30)
==4464==  Address 0x51e0048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4464==    at 0x4C2AD3C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4464==    by 0x40056C: free_list (list.c:18)
==4464==    by 0x4005DF: main (list.c:30)
```

I just added this to the program to make it testable:

```
int main() {
    nodeT head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nodeT node1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next = node1;
    head->elem = NULL;
    node1->next = NULL;
    node1->elem = NULL;

    free_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I must have missed that last part. Mine error is a bit different. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: (compile with -g to add the line numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can `memset` the node to zero before freeing the memory. Then it'll crash for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any proof other than fact that the code dereferences a pointer to memory that was freed. That's undefined behavior. Invoking undefined behavior is bad.

So there's your proof.